# How Can I Print Horizontal and vertical Histogram In C?

Tags: c

I have start to Learning C  programming language.How can I print Horizontal and vertical histogram?

Answer (score 2):

*Only because I'm bored tonight:*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[1024];
    int count[26] = {};
    
    fgets( str, sizeof str, stdin );
    for(int i=0; str[i]; ++i)
    {
        count[tolower(str[i])-'a'] += !!isalpha(str[i]);
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof count / sizeof *count; ++i)
    {
        printf("%c: %.*s\n", i+'a', count[i], "*************************************************");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

## Example run:

**Input:**

> The swimmer set a new world record in the 1,500-meter freestyle race Wednesday, taking first place at the 2018 TYR Pro Swim Series in Indianapolis. She posted a time of 15:20.48, which was five seconds better than her previous record set in 2015, per Nick Zaccardi of NBC Sports.

**Output:**

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4456KB
a: *************
b: **
c: **********
d: *********
e: ******************************
f: *****
g: *
h: ********
i: *****************
j: 
k: **
l: ****
m: *****
n: ************
o: ***********
p: *******
q: 
r: *******************
s: ******************
t: *****************
u: *
v: **
w: *******
x: 
y: ***
z: *
```

The output shows that the letter `e` is the most common, and letters `j`, `q`, and `x` do not appear at all in the sample text.