# K&R "The C Programming Language" Exercise 1-14

Tags: c

So, in this exercise I need to make a program that outputs a histogram of the frequencies of different characters in its input.
This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int c,i;
    int m = 1;
    int a[m];
 
    i = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        m++;
        a[i] = c;
        ++i;
        /* assign a a string of chars*/
    }
    i = 0;
    int r;
    int s;
    while (i<m){

        s = 0;
        for(r = 0; r < m; r++){

            if (a[r] == a[i] && a[i] != 0 && a[i] != '\n' && a[i] != EOF) {
                s++;
                /*checks for every character in the strig if there is another one that's the same and adds one to the s var*/

            }



        }
        ++i;

        putchar(a[i]);
        putchar('|');
        printf("%d", s);
        putchar('\n');
        /*ouptputs the charaters and his frequency in the input*/

    }


}
```

If we run this and we input let's say abbcd, it will output:

```
a|0
b|1
b|2
c|2
d|1
```

(It's still a working progress so its not perfect)

My problem is that if I write more than 7 characters it will run for a while without any output and than will exit with the exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

Is the problem my processor? I have a i7-3540M. I mean, I know it's bad, but this bad?

Comment: `int m = 1; int a[m];` Arrays in C do not automatically grow in size. You are overwriting memory you shouldn't resulting in Undefine Behaviour.

Comment: Another error: `i` is not set back to `0` before the first `while` loop starts.

Comment: So i got rid of the first for loop and i set the i to 0, but if i input 10 characters the same think  happened.

Comment: `a` still only holds one element. Do you know about dynamic memory management?

Comment: nope, but i updated the m in the first while loop.

Comment: That isn't how arrays work. Take a look at `malloc()`, `free()` as well as `calloc()` and `realloc()`.

Comment: The array size is fixed at the point you define it. In your case it is always a size of 1 element. Changing `m` later has no effect on the array size. Declare a bigger array or use dynamic allocation via `malloc`.

Comment: ok i'll try it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381876/how-can-i-print-horizontal-and-vertical-histogram-in-c/50382134#50382134

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no problem with your processor. The problem here is an [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In particular, with this snippet of code in the while loop:

```
a[i] = c;
```

This will only be good for `i = 0`. However, as soon as `i > 0`, this will start generating undefined behavior, since array `a` was declared to fit in only one element like so: `int m = 1; int a[m];`.

In another words, you are trying to store in an array beyond its defined boundary.

Moreover, as couple of people pointed out in the comments section, you cannot just increment `m` and expect the size of array `a` to "grow". If you want your array to "grow" in size when the program is running (and store more items in it), you must learn how to [dynamically manage your memory](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/255/Syllabus/2-C-adv-data/dyn-array.html).